Magento add store filter in system export
Here is what I did to add a field in the system export form, and override the below mentioned files in order to return only attribute value for that particular selected store for each product.

Override \Magento\ImportExport\Block\Adminhtml\Export\Edit\Form to add extra field

protected function _prepareForm()
   {
       parent::_prepareForm();
       
       $form = $this->getForm();
       /** @var Fieldset $fieldset */
       $fieldset = $form->getElement('base_fieldset');
       
       // Add store selection field
       $fieldset->addField(
           'store_id',
           'select',
           [
               'name' => 'store_id',
               'label' => __('Store View'),
               'title' => __('Store View'),
               'values' => $this->_getStoreOptions(),
               'note' => __('Choose the store view to export data from'),
           ]
       );
       
       return $this;
   }

   protected function _getStoreOptions()
   {
       $options = [['label' => __('-- Please Select --'), 'value' => '']];
       $stores = $this->_storeManager->getStores();
       
       foreach ($stores as $store) {
           $options[] = [
               'label' => $store->getName(),
               'value' => $store->getId()
           ];
       }
       
       return $options;
   }


view/adminhtml/templates/export/form/before.phtml

getFile = function() {
        if ($('entity') && \$F('entity')) {
            var form      = $('export_filter_form');
            var oldAction = form.action;
            var url = oldAction + ((oldAction.slice(-1) != '/') ? '/' : '') + 'entity/' + \$F('entity')
                + '/file_format/' + \$F('file_format');
            if (\$F('fields_enclosure')) {
                url += '/fields_enclosure/' + \$F('fields_enclosure');
            }
            // Addedd store_id to url param
            if (\$F('store_id')) {
                url += '/store_id/' + \$F('store_id');
            }
            form.action = url;
            form.submit();
            form.action   = oldAction;
        } else {
            alert({
                content: '{$block->escapeHtml(__('Invalid data'))}'
            });
        }
    };


Controller/Adminhtml/Export/Export.php - got the selected store value here.

public function execute()
   {
       if ($this->getRequest()->getPost(ExportModel::FILTER_ELEMENT_GROUP)) {
           try {
               $params = $this->getRequestParameters();

               if (!array_key_exists('skip_attr', $params)) {
                   $params['skip_attr'] = [];
               }
               /** @var ExportInfoFactory $dataObject */
               $dataObject = $this->exportInfoFactory->create(
                   $params['file_format'],
                   $params['entity'],
                   $params['store_id'],
                   $params['export_filter'],
                   $params['skip_attr'],
                   $this->localeResolver->getLocale()
               );
               
               $this->messagePublisher->publish('import_export.export', $dataObject);
               $this->messageManager->addSuccessMessage(
                   __(
                       'Message is added to queue, wait to get your file soon.'
                       . ' Make sure your cron job is running to export the file'
                   )
               );
           } catch (\Exception $e) {
               $this->_objectManager->get(\Psr\Log\LoggerInterface::class)->critical($e);
               $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage(__('Please correct the data sent value.'));
           }
       } else {
           $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage(__('Please correct the data sent value.'));
       }
       /** @var \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Redirect $resultRedirect */
       $resultRedirect = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_REDIRECT);
       $resultRedirect->setPath('adminhtml/*/index');
       return $resultRedirect;
   }


vendor/magento/module-import-export/Model/Export/Entity/ExportInfoFactory.php

public function create($fileFormat, $entity, $store_id, $exportFilter, $skipAttr = [], ?string $locale = null)
    {
        $writer = $this->getWriter($fileFormat);
        $entityAdapter = $this->getEntityAdapter(
            $entity,
            $store_id,
            $fileFormat,
            $exportFilter,
            $skipAttr,
            $writer->getContentType()
        );
        $fileName = $this->generateFileName($entity, $entityAdapter, $writer->getFileExtension());
        /** @var ExportInfoInterface $exportInfo */
        $exportInfo = $this->objectManager->create(ExportInfoInterface::class);
        $exportInfo->setExportFilter($this->serializer->serialize($exportFilter));
        $exportInfo->setSkipAttr($skipAttr);
        $exportInfo->setFileName($fileName);
        $exportInfo->setEntity($entity);
        $exportInfo->setFileFormat($fileFormat);
        $exportInfo->setContentType($writer->getContentType());
        if ($locale) {
            $exportInfo->setLocale($locale);
        }
        if ($store_id) {
            $exportInfo->setStoreId($store_id);
        }

        return $exportInfo;
    }

private function getEntityAdapter($entity, $store_id, $fileFormat, $exportFilter, $skipAttr, $contentType)
    {
        $entities = $this->exportConfig->getEntities();
        if (isset($entities[$entity])) {
            try {
                $entityAdapter = $this->entityFactory->create($entities[$entity]['model']);
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                $this->logger->critical($e);
                throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(
                    __('Please enter a correct entity model.')
                );
            }
            if (!$entityAdapter instanceof \Magento\ImportExport\Model\Export\Entity\AbstractEntity &&
                !$entityAdapter instanceof \Magento\ImportExport\Model\Export\AbstractEntity
            ) {
                throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(
                    __(
                        'The entity adapter object must be an instance of %1 or %2.',
                        \Magento\ImportExport\Model\Export\Entity\AbstractEntity::class,
                        \Magento\ImportExport\Model\Export\AbstractEntity::class
                    )
                );
            }
            // check for entity codes integrity
            if ($entity != $entityAdapter->getEntityTypeCode()) {
                throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(
                    __('The input entity code is not equal to entity adapter code.')
                );
            }
        } else {
            throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(__('Please enter a correct entity.'));
        }
        $entityAdapter->setParameters(
            [
                'fileFormat' => $fileFormat,
                'entity' => $entity,
                'storeId' => $store_id,
                'exportFilter' => $exportFilter,
                'skipAttr' => $skipAttr,
                'contentType' => $contentType,
            ]
        );
        return $entityAdapter;
    }


\Magento\CatalogImportExport\Model\Export\Product

public function setParameters(array $parameters)
    {
        // Capture the parameters
        parent::setParameters($parameters);
        // Set the store ID if it exists in the parameters
        if (isset($parameters['storeId'])) {
            $this->storeId = $parameters['storeId'];
        }

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get entity collection
     *
     * @param bool $resetCollection
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb
     */
    protected function _getEntityCollection($resetCollection = false)
    {
        // if ($resetCollection || empty($this->_entityCollection)) {
        //     $this->_entityCollection = $this->_entityCollectionFactory->create();
        // }
        // Apply store filter if store ID is set
        if ($this->storeId) {
            $this->_entityCollection->setStoreId($this->storeId);
        }

        return $this->_entityCollection;
    }
    

But its not working. no change in the exported file listing values for all of the stores. Any help is appreciated.

You've done a great job outlining your approach and the steps you've taken to implement the store filter in Magento's export functionality. Let's refine and ensure the details are coherent and correctly implemented. Here is a structured step-by-step approach to achieve your goal.
Step-by-Step Implementation
1. Create a Custom Module
You already have a custom module setup. Ensure your module is properly registered and enabled.
2. Override the Export Form
File: app/code/Vendor/Module/Block/Adminhtml/Export/Edit/Form.php
Extend the form to add the store filter field:
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Export\Edit;

use Magento\ImportExport\Block\Adminhtml\Export\Edit\Form as BaseForm;

class Form extends BaseForm
{
    protected function _prepareForm()
    {
        parent::_prepareForm();
        
        $form = $this->getForm();
        $fieldset = $form->getElement('base_fieldset');
        
        $fieldset->addField(
            'store_id',
            'select',
            [
                'name' => 'store_id',
                'label' => __('Store View'),
                'title' => __('Store View'),
                'values' => $this->_getStoreOptions(),
                'note' => __('Choose the store view to export data from'),
            ]
        );
        
        return $this;
    }

    protected function _getStoreOptions()
    {
        $options = [['label' => __('-- Please Select --'), 'value' => '']];
        $stores = $this->_storeManager->getStores();
        
        foreach ($stores as $store) {
            $options[] = [
                'label' => $store->getName(),
                'value' => $store->getId()
            ];
        }
        
        return $options;
    }
}

3. Update the Export Form Template
File: app/code/Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/templates/export/form/before.phtml
Update the form submission script to include the store ID:
getFile = function() {
    if ($('entity') && $F('entity')) {
        var form = $('export_filter_form');
        var oldAction = form.action;
        var url = oldAction + ((oldAction.slice(-1) != '/') ? '/' : '') + 'entity/' + $F('entity')
            + '/file_format/' + $F('file_format');
        if ($F('fields_enclosure')) {
            url += '/fields_enclosure/' + $F('fields_enclosure');
        }
        if ($F('store_id')) {
            url += '/store_id/' + $F('store_id');
        }
        form.action = url;
        form.submit();
        form.action = oldAction;
    } else {
        alert({
            content: '{$block->escapeHtml(__('Invalid data'))}'
        });
    }
};

4. Update the Export Controller
File: app/code/Vendor/Module/Controller/Adminhtml/Export/Export.php
Modify the controller to handle the store ID:
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Controller\Adminhtml\Export;

use Magento\ImportExport\Controller\Adminhtml\Export\Export as BaseExport;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;
use Magento\ImportExport\Model\Export as ExportModel;

class Export extends BaseExport
{
    public function execute()
    {
        if ($this->getRequest()->getPost(ExportModel::FILTER_ELEMENT_GROUP)) {
            try {
                $params = $this->getRequestParameters();

                if (!array_key_exists('skip_attr', $params)) {
                    $params['skip_attr'] = [];
                }
                $dataObject = $this->exportInfoFactory->create(
                    $params['file_format'],
                    $params['entity'],
                    $params['store_id'],
                    $params['export_filter'],
                    $params['skip_attr'],
                    $this->localeResolver->getLocale()
                );
                
                $this->messagePublisher->publish('import_export.export', $dataObject);
                $this->messageManager->addSuccessMessage(
                    __('Message is added to queue, wait to get your file soon. Make sure your cron job is running to export the file')
                );
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                $this->_objectManager->get(\Psr\Log\LoggerInterface::class)->critical($e);
                $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage(__('Please correct the data sent value.'));
            }
        } else {
            $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage(__('Please correct the data sent value.'));
        }
        $resultRedirect = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_REDIRECT);
        $resultRedirect->setPath('adminhtml/*/index');
        return $resultRedirect;
    }
}

5. Update the Export Info Factory
File: vendor/magento/module-import-export/Model/Export/Entity/ExportInfoFactory.php
Modify the factory to handle the store ID:
public function create($fileFormat, $entity, $store_id, $exportFilter, $skipAttr = [], ?string $locale = null)
{
    $writer = $this->getWriter($fileFormat);
    $entityAdapter = $this->getEntityAdapter(
        $entity,
        $store_id,
        $fileFormat,
        $exportFilter,
        $skipAttr,
        $writer->getContentType()
    );
    $fileName = $this->generateFileName($entity, $entityAdapter, $writer->getFileExtension());
    $exportInfo = $this->objectManager->create(ExportInfoInterface::class);
    $exportInfo->setExportFilter($this->serializer->serialize($exportFilter));
    $exportInfo->setSkipAttr($skipAttr);
    $exportInfo->setFileName($fileName);
    $exportInfo->setEntity($entity);
    $exportInfo->setFileFormat($fileFormat);
    $exportInfo->setContentType($writer->getContentType());
    if ($locale) {
        $exportInfo->setLocale($locale);
    }
    if ($store_id) {
        $exportInfo->setStoreId($store_id);
    }

    return $exportInfo;
}

private function getEntityAdapter($entity, $store_id, $fileFormat, $exportFilter, $skipAttr, $contentType)
{
    $entities = $this->exportConfig->getEntities();
    if (isset($entities[$entity])) {
        try {
            $entityAdapter = $this->entityFactory->create($entities[$entity]['model']);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->logger->critical($e);
            throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(
                __('Please enter a correct entity model.')
            );
        }
        if (!$entityAdapter instanceof \Magento\ImportExport\Model\Export\Entity\AbstractEntity &&
            !$entityAdapter instanceof \Magento\ImportExport\Model\Export\AbstractEntity
        ) {
            throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(
                __(
                    'The entity adapter object must be an instance of %1 or %2.',
                    \Magento\ImportExport\Model\Export\Entity\AbstractEntity::class,
                    \Magento\ImportExport\Model\Export\AbstractEntity::class
                )
            );
        }
        if ($entity != $entityAdapter->getEntityTypeCode()) {
            throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(
                __('The input entity code is not equal to entity adapter code.')
            );
        }
    } else {
        throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(__('Please enter a correct entity.'));
    }
    $entityAdapter->setParameters(
        [
            'fileFormat' => $fileFormat,
            'entity' => $entity,
            'storeId' => $store_id,
            'exportFilter' => $exportFilter,
            'skipAttr' => $skipAttr,
            'contentType' => $contentType,
        ]
    );
    return $entityAdapter;
}

6. Update the Product Export Model
File: app/code/Vendor/Module/Model/Export/Product.php
Extend the product export model to handle the store ID:
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Model\Export;

use Magento\CatalogImportExport\Model\Export\Product as BaseProduct;

class Product extends BaseProduct
{
    protected $storeId;

    public function setParameters(array $parameters)
    {
        parent::setParameters($parameters);
        if (isset($parameters['storeId'])) {
            $this->storeId = $parameters['storeId'];
        }
        return $this;
    }

    protected function _getEntityCollection($resetCollection = false)
    {
        if ($resetCollection || empty($this->_entityCollection)) {
            $this->_entityCollection = $this->_entityCollectionFactory->create();
        }
        if ($this->storeId) {
            $this->_entityCollection->setStoreId($this->storeId);
        }
        return $this->_entityCollection;
    }
}

Final Steps

Enable and Deploy the Module:

php bin/magento module:enable Vendor_Module
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento cache:flush


Test the Export Functionality:

Go to the Magento admin panel.
Navigate to the export section.
Select the store view from the new store filter dropdown.
Perform the export and verify that the data corresponds to the selected store view.



By following these steps, you should be able to successfully add a store filter to Magento's export functionality, ensuring that the exported data corresponds to the selected

Hi @Amal, Thanks for the clarifications, This is exactly what I did. Still  something is missing. not working. getting values of default store only. not the selected one.

The method
if ($store_id) {
$exportInfo->setStoreId($store_id);
}
in exportInfoFactory has resulted the error -
Call to undefined method setStoreId()
